# Alinear un párrafo con una lista desordenada

Tags: css

Estoy con el siguiente problema, como verán en la imagen tengo un rectángulo que dice "01 SEMESTRE", ese es una etiqueta de párrafo obviamente está rotada y lo que necesito es acomodarlo en línea con la lista desordenada que ahí se ve.

¿Cómo podria lograr esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo html y css que tengo hasta este momento

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
   <tr>
   <td style="background-color: #2DBCC0; width: 50px; border-radius: 3px; padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px;">
    <img src="img/puntos.png" width="50" style="display: block; margin: 30px auto 10px;">
    <img src="img/cc03.png" width="80" style="margin-bottom: 8px;">
    <img src="img/cc04.png" width="80" style="margin-bottom: 8px;">
   </td>
   <td style="background-color: #FDDDC7; border-radius: 3px; padding-left: 8px; padding-right: 8px;">
    <h5 style="color: #F58634;">PLAN DE ESTUDIOS</h5>
    <div style="background-color: #0000ff; display: table;">
    <p style="display: block; background-color: #2DBCC0; padding: 4px 3px; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: bold; -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); transform: rotate(-90deg); margin-left: 0; float: left;">
      01 SEMESTRE</p>   
    <ul  style="font-size: 15px; background-color: #ff0000; width: 90%; float: right;">
    <li><span>Fundamenetos clínicos del abusador y de la victima maltratada y abusada</span></li> 
    <li><span>Detección y tratamiento del abuso sexual</span></li> 
    <li><span>Personas y Familia</span></li> 
    <li><span>Derecho Penal</span></li> 
    </ul>

    </div>
   </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Recuerda que para que sea mas facil ayudarte debes poner el codigo de lo que llevas.

Comment: comparte tu código html y css para poder ayudarte, [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/157103/edit) tu pregunta

Comment: es necesario que este todo en una tabla?

Comment: No no es necesario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solo es trabajar un poco el estilo, ¿es así como lo quieres? **Pulsa Ejecutar**

```html
<table style="width: 100%;">
   <tr>
   <td style="background-color: #2DBCC0; width: 50px; border-radius: 3px; padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px;">
    <img src="img/puntos.png" width="50" style="display: block; margin: 30px auto 10px;">
    <img src="img/cc03.png" width="80" style="margin-bottom: 8px;">
    <img src="img/cc04.png" width="80" style="margin-bottom: 8px;">
   </td>
   <td style="background-color: #FDDDC7; border-radius: 3px; padding-left: 8px; padding-right: 8px;">
    <h5 style="color: #F58634;">PLAN DE ESTUDIOS</h5>
    <div style="background-color: #0000ff; display: table;">
    <p style="display: block; background-color: #2DBCC0; padding: 4px 3px; color: #FFFFFF; margin-top: 42px; position: absolute; font-weight: bold; -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); transform: rotate(-90deg); margin-left: -50px; float: left;">
      01 SEMESTRE</p>   
    <ul  style="font-size: 15px; background-color: #ff0000; width: 90%; float: right;">
    <li><span>Fundamenetos clínicos del abusador y de la victima maltratada y abusada</span></li> 
    <li><span>Detección y tratamiento del abuso sexual</span></li> 
    <li><span>Personas y Familia</span></li> 
    <li><span>Derecho Penal</span></li> 
    </ul>

    </div>
   </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```